# Mac geopandas import error

Tags: python, macos, geopandas

I am having some trouble trying to import geopandas in my Mac. I installed it by the conda command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
```

After I try to import by I get the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-e508418be6dd> in <module>()
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 import geopandas as gpd
      3 get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geopandas/__init__.py in <module>()
      2 from geopandas.geodataframe import GeoDataFrame
      3 
----> 4 from geopandas.io.file import read_file
      5 from geopandas.io.sql import read_postgis
      6 from geopandas.tools import sjoin

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/geopandas/io/file.py in <module>()
      1 import os
      2 
----> 3 import fiona
      4 import numpy as np
      5 

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fiona/__init__.py in <module>()
     67 from six import string_types
     68 
---> 69 from fiona.collection import Collection, BytesCollection, vsi_path
     70 from fiona._drivers import driver_count, GDALEnv
     71 from fiona.drvsupport import supported_drivers

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fiona/collection.py in <module>()
      7 
      8 from fiona import compat
----> 9 from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
     10 from fiona.ogrext import Session, WritingSession
     11 from fiona.ogrext import (

ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fiona/ogrext.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libxerces-c-3.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

I tried updating my anaconda by running:

```
conda update conda
```

Got the same error, so I tried uninstalling with conda and installing with pip. Got the same error.

Then I tried to forge fiona with conda,then installing with pip but it got me nowhere, and now I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think could have been a problem with the conda-forge feedstock for fiona:
https://github.com/conda-forge/fiona-feedstock/issues/62

I had the same problem a few days ago but it seems to have been resolved now. Have you tried again?